# Update function's internal properties using a function outside it's scope in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Super simple abstracted example, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can invoke `updateAge()` from within `doMainStuff` to update the `person` object's `age` property? Is this where call() or apply() come into play?

```
function doMainStuff() {
    var person = {
        name: 'Bob',
        age: 55
    }

    updateAge();
}


function updateAge(){
    person.age = 24;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass the `person` object to your `updateAge` function:

```
function doMainStuff () {
    var person = {
        name: 'Bob',
        age: 55
    };

    updateAge(person);
}


function updateAge (person) {
    person.age = 24;
}
```

Comment: That was simple. I was under the impression 'person' would only update within the context of 'updateAge', but this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgLtx/) proves otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joseph Silber's answer: in JS all objects are passed by *reference*: if you put in an object as a function parameter you actually pass in *a reference to the same object*. This means that if the function changes the parameter object's properties, these remain changed after the function call that changed it returns.

Answer (score 1):

If you define proper classes in JavaScript you can use methods defined by them.

```
function Person(name, age) {
    var privateVariable = "special";
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.updateAge = function() {
    this.age = 24;
}

function doStuff() {
    var person = new Person("Bob", 55);
    person.updateAge(); // will work
    person.age = 24; // will also work
    typeof(person.privateVariable) == 'undefined'; // it's only defined within the Person function/class
}
```